# function(ascii, a, b, c) ascii code puzzle

Tags: javascript, encryption

I'm working on a code puzzle which uses the following script:

```
    function(ascii,a,b,c) {
        for(i=0;i<ascii.length;i++) {
            if(i%3==0){ascii[i]=(ascii[i]+a)%256;}
            if(i%3==1){ascii[i]=(ascii[i]+b)%256;}
            if(i%3==2){ascii[i]=(ascii[i]+c)%256;}
        }
        return ascii;
    }
```

I think it says: ' for each character in the message (or if the message is an array, for each element i in the array), calculate its position mod3, and depending on the result add either a, b or c to the ascii value for the character, and then return that value mod 256. Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: `ascii[i]` will be the character, not the ASCII value. Assuming `ascii` is a string, that is.

Comment: This only makes sense if ascii is an array, not a string. Since strings are immutable `ascii[i] = ascii[i] + a` will not change anything in a string. So I expect ascii to be an array, maybe formed by `someWord.split('')`, but I'm thinking it's going to be an array of numbers, representing the ascii value of each letter, since the modulo 256 of a string doesn't make sense either. Something like `[45,78,52,55,78,99]` ?

Comment: @Shilly I've made an edit regarding the array - for the question, is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Your interpretation is correct indeed. Just watch out with what the inputs to it are. When callling the fn, you probably want to use (array, int, int, int) as the types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an `encoding function` which takes an `array` of numbers representing `characters (0-255)`. Then shifts the characters by the length specified as per `a,b, and c by modding by 3`. Then the output is `modded by 255` so it remains a valid character value. Finally the resulting encoding `array of numbers representing characters` is returned.

Below is the code:

```
function encodeIt(ascii,a,b,c) {
    for(i=0;i<ascii.length;i++) {
        if(i%3==0){ascii[i]=(ascii[i]+a)%256;}
        if(i%3==1){ascii[i]=(ascii[i]+b)%256;}
        if(i%3==2){ascii[i]=(ascii[i]+c)%256;}
    }
    return ascii;
}

function encodeString(myString,myAdjustments)
{
    var myArray = [];
    for(var i=0;i<myString.length;i++)
    {
        myArray.push(myString.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    var myArray = encodeIt(myArray,myAdjustments[0],myAdjustments[1],myAdjustments[2]);
    var myEncodedString = "";
    for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
    {
        myEncodedString+=String.fromCharCode(myArray[i]);
    }
    return myEncodedString;
}

var encodedString = encodeString("Hello World!",[30,80,-13]);
alert(encodedString);
var decodedString = encodeString(encodedString,[-30,-80,13]);
alert(decodedString);
```

And the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3p79bxv2/

Comment: awaiting your fiddle!

Comment: @TMrtSmith: Did it do any help?

Comment: thanks, that's helpful. I have an encoded array and now need to work backward to find the plaintext, but I didn't want to just ask stack for the answer (no cheating!)